# Проблемы с русским при использовании PHPExcel, mysqli

Tags: mysqli, utf-8, phpexcel

Привет, нужна помощь по следующему вопросу.

При попытке сформировать Excel файл (c использованием PHPExcel) все строки на русском становятся не читабельными.
Таблицы в базе используют кодировку - utf8_general_ci, PHP скрипт в UTF-8.
Окружение: CentOS v6.6 x64, PHP 5.3.3, Apache 2.2.15.

При этом в браузере все выводится читабельно, а в файле Excel нет.

Что делать, кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой ?

Испробовал все,

1. Конвертировал файл в UTF-8 с BOM
2. Конвертировал файл в UTF-8 без BOM
3. Конвертировал строку с русскими словами c UTF-8 в CP1251, не помогло:

   ```
   mb_convert_encoding($row["title"],"cp1251","utf8");
   iconv("utf8", "cp1251", $row["title"]);
   ```

Что делать ?

Мой PHP код (убрано все лишнее, сам файл в utf-8):

```
<?php
require_once('PHPExcel.php');
$db_servername = "localhost";
$db_username = "пользоват";
$db_password = "пароль";
$db_name = "база";

$conn = new mysqli($db_servername, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
$conn->set_charset("utf8"); // устанавливал и cp1251, не помогло

$sql = "SELECT poster,title FROM table where t_id='1' Limit 1;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

$xls = new PHPExcel();
// Устанавливаем индекс активного листа
$xls->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
// Получаем активный лист
$sheet = $xls->getActiveSheet();
// Подписываем лист
$sheet->setTitle('Отчет');

// Заносим данные в файл Excelб если встречаются русские слова, то они нечитабельны
$sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1,1,$row["title"]);

// Сохраняем файл
header ( "Expires: Mon, 1 Apr 1974 05:00:00 GMT" );
header ( "Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT" );
header ( "Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate" );
header ( "Pragma: no-cache" );
header ( "Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel" );
header ( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=matrix.xlsx" );

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($xls, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');

?>
```

Вот такую строку я получаю в файле Excel. Английское 'RE:' отображается, а то что дальше по русский нет.:

```
RE: &#1079;&#1072;&#1082;&#1072;&#1079;
```

Буду благодарен любому совету. Спасибо!

Comment: Вы можете исправлять свой вопрос нажав на ссылку Править ниже вопроса.